# Retrieve Serial Number of external USB flash drive using IOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, usb

Looking to get the Serial Number of USB flash drive connected with iPhone device. I know it is possible to get serial number using EAAccessory:

[serialnumber](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory/eaaccessory/1613811-serialnumber)

but this will need to know the protocol specification of MFI hardware.

Alternatively, I am able to connect USB flash drive using Lightening to OTG connector and able to transfer data to it. Now I need to get serial number of connected flash drive without using EAAccessory Framework.